# Calculating an Average from booleans with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, algorithm, average

I have a setup in which there are 10 attributes that accept a float in a rails form. Each attribute also is associated with a value in my model. If a number is entered on the form for more than one attribute, I need to create a weighted average.

An example would be if I have 10 products, each having a price in my model. In the form, a user can enter in the amount (number of products) for each product. I'd like to calculate a weighted price for those products that have an amount entered.

So how can I create a weighted average that checks which products have amounts entered?

Comment: how do you identify which all fields are selected?
do you send all in params or only selected one's

Comment: I'm sending all params right now, don't really know how to send only selected ones

Comment: Are you using CGI, or is this code running inside Rails or Sinatra or something similar? They can help by returning arrays of values, making it trivial to loop over the ones you want. How you set up your form can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columns_names = ['a','b','c','d'] # array of name of the columns

obj = Model.find(:id) # find the object with id

# loop and get column values that are set

values = columns_names.inject([]) do |arr,column_name|
  arr << obj.column_name if params[column_name].eql?"true" # collect the values if the column set
  arr
end

#get average
if values.blank?
  # no column selected
else
  avg =  values.reduce(:+)/values.size
end
```

check this for help on weighted average

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/weighted-mean

Comment: Sorry, I think this works but I've actually realized that I need a weighted average now. I've updated the original question above - is there a way to tweak this code to work for a weighted average?

Comment: just replace `values.reduce(:+)/values.size` with a `function` that calculates weighted average

Comment: @user1486809, added a link for help on weighted average

Answer (score 1):

This code retrieves all attributes that are true on your model:

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id)
@model.attributes.select{|k,v| (v.is_a?(TrueClass) || v.is_a?(FalseClass)) && v}
```

If you want the false ones just do a:

```
@model.attributes.select{|k,v| (v.is_a?(TrueClass) || v.is_a?(FalseClass)) && !v}
```

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but maybe it can clear your head a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not sure how I can apply it. I guess it would tell me which of the booleans (if more than one) were selected, but not sure how I can specify the boolean part if this code returns all of the attributes.